# Two tikzpicture overlap each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

For some reason, I have to draw two tikzpicture and these two picture may overlap each other. An MWE is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz\fill[blue](0,0)circle(1); \kern-0.5cm\tikz \fill[red](0,0)circle(1);

\end{document}
```

The latter picture(red) will cover the former one(blue), but I just want the former one to cover the latter one. If they inside the same tikzpicture, we could use the layer. But they are in two tikzpicture, so how to make it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Swap the order of the tikzpictures and use a longer length for the kern?

Comment: If swapd, the same happens. Say, the latter one covers the former one. But what I want is just the former one covers the latter one.

Comment: Ehm, one of us misunderstands the other. Now you have `a <kern> b`, so `b` covers `a`. If you do `b <larger kern> a`, then `a` will  cover `b` which is what you want? Or is is somehow required to have `a` before `b` in the code? But on second thought it's not a very good idea anyway, because you probably need some extra space before the first `tikzpicture` in addition ...

Comment: Emm, I mean if two tikzpicture overlap. How to make the first drawing cover the second drawing.

Comment: `\hspace{1.4cm}\tikz\fill[red](0,0)circle(1); \kern-3.5cm\tikz \fill[blue](0,0)circle(1);` The `\hspace` at the start is why this is a bad idea.

Comment: You still don't understand me. If you draw the red first and blue second, I want the red on the main layer and the blue on the background layer, so the red circle is complete. If you draw the blue first and red second, I want the blue on the main layer and the red on the background layer, so the blue circle is complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107788/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-misaya).

Comment: I feel very soory that my web is so bad to connect to chat.

Comment: I'll just say one more thing then, I do think what I suggest give the same result as what you say you want to do, it just does it in a different way. But perhaps there's something I'm missing. Anyways, complete example: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/8c97a755c7efef7a04bc9c694ef22feb

Comment: You draw the red first and the blue second. So i want the red to be on the main layer but you make the red on the background layer.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: (This will probably be my final comment, one of us is still misunderstanding the other.) *What is the difference in the result?* Did you look at the example in my link? You want to place first a blue then a red blob next to each other on the page, then move the red a little bit to the left, below the blue one. But when moving left it comes on top. I suggest placing first the red one, then the blue one next to it, and moving the blue one a much further distance to the left. It's bad because you then have to move *both* some distance to the right, but the end result is what I think you ask for.

Comment: Of cource I've compiled your code. But this is not a matter of length or color. What I want is not that the blue is on the above or the red is on the above. It's a matter of their orders. If the blue is drawn first, the blue should on the above. If the red is drawn first, then the red should be on the above. In your example, the red is drawn first but the blue is on the above.